# How to send An Image Using Socket programming in android (client to local server)

Tags: android

basically what I'm doing is, I want to send a picture to a local server using TCP/IP. I preferred to use AsyncTask because the process will be detecting first if there is wifi then start syncing images to the server.

I'll appreciate any help.
the server code is written in Delphi.

Here is the code:

```
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new SendImageTask().execute();
        }
    });

    public class SendImageTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/inspections/Lol.bmp");
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
         socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP),SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int nread = 0;
        try {
            if (bis != null) {
                nread = bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (nread != mybytearray.length) return null;
        OutputStream ost = null;
        try {
            if (socket != null) {
                ost = socket.getOutputStream();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (ost != null) {
                ost.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (ost != null) {
                ost.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);`. Change to `int nread = bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);` and see that `nread!=mybytearray.length`.

Comment: Can you please clarify this : bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);. Change to int nread = bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); and see that nread!=mybytearray.length.

Comment: I tried it and i'm getting a broken pipe message. (Java.net.SocketException: Bronken Pipe)